# How can I get number of rows update for a update statement?

Tags: python, google-cloud-spanner

I am running this inside a transaction...

```
def update_session(transaction):
    global code
    global sessionexists
    count = transaction.execute_sql("update sessions set seentime=@t where sessioncode=@s", params={"s":code,"t":datetime.utcnow()}, 
       param_types={"t": spanner.param_types.TIMESTAMP})
    print("count "+str(count))
    sessionexists = 0
    for c in count:
        print(c)
        sessionexists = c
```

This does not seem to return number of rows updated...
Is there way to do it?
Solution:
Based on the valid answer...this seems to work as well

```
count = transaction.execute_update("update sessions set seentime=@t where sessioncode=@s", params={"s":code,"t":datetime.utcnow()}, 
       param_types={"s": spanner.param_types.STRING,"t": spanner.param_types.TIMESTAMP})
count is the number of rows
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace the `execute_sql` function call with `execute_update`. `execute_sql` is intended for queries that return rows. `execute_update` is intended for DML statements.

See also this code example for how to execute DML statements using the Python client: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/samples/spanner-dml-standard-update#spanner_dml_standard_update-python